# Exact representation of integers

Tags: r, integer, data-representation

I know that in Java there is the class BigInteger, that permits to treat the integers in their full representation via Strings. Is there something similar in R? I use integers to represent indices in my data structure, and I need to keep that representation as exact as possible and hence not to obtain indices such as ``7.897557e+14''. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which do you want?  Arbitrary precision integers or non-auto-floating numbers?

Comment: The first solution (see the title)!

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. What problems have you run into? If you need to use up to 64-bit integers you can use the [bit64 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) but the display of scientific notation for a number does not mean lack of precision. If you're looking for a way to use a "string" as a lookup mechanism, take a look at the [hash](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) package.

Comment: The folk that proposed his solution before was right: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/Rmpfr.pdf and s gmp were the best choices: he understood.